# presentModalViewController from TableView

Tags: uiviewcontroller, delegates, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have created a custom cell with buttons.
the buttons should present a modalViewController, one for the email and another for a webView.
I have also created a delegate to get a callback from the class.

so in the cell class:

```
 _delegateAction = [[HistoryVC alloc] init];
    _delegateAction.delegate = self; 
    [_delegateAction openData:_data Type:_title.text]; //start process
```

The class that the table is on is a UIviewController that have a table view. the (with the custome cells that are another class inherit from UiTableViewCell.

if you need meed information just tell me.

in the UIviewController I am trying to present a modal view as follow:

```
-(void) openData: (NSString *)data Type:(NSString*)type
{
    QRWebView * webView = [[QRWebView alloc] init];
    webView.url = data;
    [self presentModalViewController: webView animated:YES];
}
```

The modalview doesn't show. I know that I'm doing something wrong, but what is it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix it by implementing the PresentModalView.

What I did is to create a showModal and DismissModal in the AppDelegate class.

Those method add to the Window the view I wanted by adding it as:

```
[Window addsubview TheView];
```

and for the Dismiss is removeFromSuperview.

I implemented an animation to fake the modalView animation.

to get to those methods I have used the shareApplication.

and it's works.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a new view controller with `_delegateAction = [[HistoryVC alloc] init];` but you haven't made it part of the controller hierarchy by presenting it in any way.

When you call `[self presentModalViewController: webView animated:YES];`, your `self` is the new controller and, since it's not in the hierarchy, it's not capable of presenting another controller.

Comment: I assume you know which view controller is handling the display at the time you want to switch to the `QRWebView`.  Have **that one** call `presentModalViewController`.

Comment: I thought it self, but self doesn't do anything. I am new to xcode, and as far as I understood the self is the one that presenting the view. Please help

Comment: For any code you write, `self` is an object of the class that the code is in.  So, in what you posted, `self` is a `HistoryVC` object.  The problem is that it's a new one you just created.  You need a reference to a UIViewController that's already in control of the screen...whichever one contains your table view.

Comment: How can I use it as a reference? I am sorry I am confused.

Comment: Please, I have no clue how to perform that, would it help to present all the class?

Comment: _delegateAction = [[HistoryVC alloc] init];
    _delegateAction.delegate = self; 
    [_delegateAction openData:_data Type:_title.text]; //start process                                                              The code above is placed on a TableviewCell and not on a uiviewController, how can I make it in the hierarchy?